# Understanding in depth change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Good morning/everyone,

I'm writing to understand the process of changing of basis,fundamental in my course of linear algebra even for specific equivalence relations and 'Quotiens'.

I saw there are some questions down-voted about but I'd like to see the whole process with you to examine it in detail.

One prerequisite is the Coordinates Isomorphism, which, given a vector space V of dimension n, sends one vector v in in the column of n scalar that 'composed' that vector,

In the sense that if the vector was $v = a_{1}v_{1}+ \cdots + a_{n}v_{n}$ sends $v \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}\\ . \\ . \\ . \\ a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$

So :$$[]_{B} : V $\longmapsto \mathbb{K}^{n}$$ define as above is our isomorphism.

So now we can consider f : $V \longmapsto W$, f $\in$ HOM(V,W) and we can suppose to fix a bais $B = \{v_{1} \cdots v_{n} \}$ of V and an other $D = \{w_{1} \cdots w_{n} \} $ of W.

Observe that in this way we have implicitly said that dim V = n and dim W = m.

Through the Coordinates Isomorphisms we have the following diagramm :

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V @>{{f}}>> W\\
@V []_{B}VV @VV []_{D}V\\
\mathbb{K}^{n} @>{M_{D}^{B}}>> \mathbb{K}^{m}
\end{CD}

Where $M_{D}^{B}$ represents the matrix of changing basis from the basis B to the basis D.

At this point knowing that the composition of linear function is still linear we know that $$[]_{D} \circ f \circ []_{{B}^{-1}} \in HOM(\mathbb{K}^{n},\mathbb{K}^{m})$$

And we identify $[]_{D} \circ f \circ []_{{B}^{-1}}$ with $M_{D}^{B}$ and here's my question.

Observe that $[]_{{B}^{-1}}$ exists because $[]_{B}$ is an isomorphism.

The prove follows saying that we know everything of this matrix, in the sense that we know the link between this M  and the application, because :

$\forall v \in V [f(v)]_{D} = M_{D}^{B}  (f) \circ [v]_{B}$ and so the matrix it's of the form : $$ \begin{pmatrix} [f(v_{1})]_{D} && \cdots && [f(v_{n})]_{D} \end{pmatrix}$$.

I don't get this passage,and so why the matrix has to be in that form, i know we're making with our hands a matrix that respects the relations, but i still don't see clearly the logic behind that brings my matrix forcely to be in that form.

Seeing the problem in a more 'handy' way we could :

- Consider the first vector of the basis V, $v_{1}$
- Calculate its image thorugh $f$, $ f(v_{1}) \in W$
- Calculate the Coordinate of $ f(v_{1})$ respect to the basis D.

And this is the Matrix of change basis.

So $A^{i} = [f(v_{i})]_{D}$ and we can write $f(v_{i}) = A_{1}^{i} w_{1} + \cdots A_{m}^{i} w_{m}$.

(This is i think because every vector in W can be written an element of the basis W, but i don't get again the relation with $A^{i}$ , or the form $A_{j}^{i}$ for $j = 1 \cdots m$ again.)

Then we take $v \in V$, with $$v = a_{1}v_{1}+ \cdots + a_{n}v_{n}$$

Applying $f \in HOM(V,W) $ : $$f(v) = a_{1}f(v_{1})+ \cdots + a_{n}f(v_{n})$$

The crucial passage starts now when we equals this to : $$a_{1}(A_{1}^{1} w_{1} + \cdots A_{m}^{1} w_{m}) + \cdots + a_{n}(A_{1}^{n} w_{1} + \cdots A_{m}^{n} w_{m})$$

I see this all follow from $f(v_{i}) = A_{1}^{i} w_{1} + \cdots A_{m}^{i} w_{m}$ i think, that is the form i am unable to understand.

This equivalent form finishes saying that : $$a_{1}(A_{1}^{1} w_{1} + \cdots A_{m}^{1} w_{m}) + \cdots + a_{n}(A_{1}^{n} w_{1} + \cdots A_{m}^{n} w_{m}) = (a_{1}A_{1}^{1} + \cdots a_{n}A_{1}^{n}) w_{1}+ \cdots + (a_{1}A_{1}^{m} + \cdots a_{n}A_{m}^{n}) w_{m})$$

(By the way, are all the index correct?)

And consequently $$[f(v)]_{D} = \begin{pmatrix} (a_{1}A_{1}^{1} + \cdots + a_{n}A_{1}^{n}) \\ . \\ . \\ . \\ a_{1}A_{m}^{1} + \cdots + a_{n}A_{m}^{n}) \end{pmatrix} $$.

If all this index are correctly placed and my speach it's true could you explain me in detail how it works ? Maybe with one appropriate example.

Theory is also good but the problem could be easier understood with one example.

Any tip to approaching this kind of problem and deal with that is also good, thanks a lots!

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. To sum up, do you want to know why the associated matrix $M_f(B_1,B_2)$ of a linear transformation $f:E_1\to E_2$ (being $B_1$ and $B_2$ basis of $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively) is unique?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Tenorio Yes,if you could explain it in detail I'd really apreciated, because i think i'm not getting all the steps that are necessary to see that actually the matrix is of that specific form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the proof we will use the following notation, $\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1\\\cdots\\\mu_r\end{pmatrix}_B:=\lambda_1b_1+\dots+\lambda_rb_n$, being $B:=\{b_1,\dots,b_r\}$ a basis of some vector space $E$ over $\mathbb{K}$ and $\mu_i\in\mathbb{K}$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,r\}$.

Given a linear transformation $f$ between two vector spaces $E_1$ and $E_2$ (both of them over the same field $\mathbb{K}$), and given two basis $B_1:=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}\subset E_1$ and $B_2:=\{e_1',\dots,e_m'\}\subset E_2$.

First of all we will see that $f$ is completely determined by the images of the vectors of $B_1$, that is, if there is another linear transformation $g$ such that $g(e_i)=f(e_i)$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, then $f=g$. To prove this, we must remember that, given a vector $x\in E_1$, its coordinates with respect to $B_1$ are unique.

Here we go with the proof, lets suppose $x=\lambda_1e_1+\dots+\lambda_ne_n$, so \begin{equation}
f(x)=f(\lambda_1e_1+\dots+\lambda_ne_n)=\lambda_1f(e_1)+\dots+\lambda_nf(e_n)
\end{equation}
So, if we have a linear transformation $g$ such that $g(e_i)=f(e_i)$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in E_1$, in other words, $f=g$.

Lets go further, lets write $f(x)\in E_2$ in coordinates with respect to $B_2$, for this, lets suppose $f(e_i)=\alpha_{1i}e_1'+\dots+\alpha_{mi}e_m'$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rc}
f(x)=&\lambda_1f(e_1)+\dots+\lambda_nf(e_n)=\\
=&\lambda_1(\alpha_{11}e_1'+\dots+\alpha_{m1}e_m')+\dots+\lambda_n(\alpha_{1n}e_1'+\dots+\alpha_{mn}e_m')=\\
=&(\lambda_1\alpha_{11}e_1'+\dots+\lambda_1\alpha_{m1}e_m')+\dots+(\lambda_n\alpha_{1n}e_1'+\dots+\lambda_n\alpha_{mn}e_m')=\\
=&(\lambda_1\alpha_{11}+\dots+\lambda_n\alpha_{1n})e_1'+\dots+(\lambda_1\alpha_{m1}+\dots+\lambda_n\alpha_{mn})e_m'
\end{array}
\end{equation}
We can write this with our notation as
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\alpha_{11}+\dots+\lambda_n\alpha_{1n}\\\cdots\\\lambda_1\alpha_{m1}+\dots+\lambda_n\alpha_{mn}\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{11}& \cdots & \alpha_{1n}\\&\cdots&\\\alpha_{m1}&\cdots&\alpha_{mn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\\cdots\\\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}
\end{equation}
Lets call $A:=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{11}& \cdots & \alpha_{1n}\\&\cdots&\\\alpha_{m1}&\cdots&\alpha_{mn}\end{pmatrix}$. Notice that the columns of this matrix are the coordinates with respect to $B_2$ of $f(e_i)$, which are unique. Lets also call $X:=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\\cdots\\\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$.

So, to sum up we have found that $f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}AX\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}$ for all $x\in E_1$, if there is another way to do so, that is $f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}CX\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}$ for all $x\in E_1$, then $\begin{pmatrix}AX\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}=\begin{pmatrix}CX\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}$, and that is equivalent, by uniqueness of the coordinates to $AX=CX\iff AX-CX=0\iff (A-C)X=0$ for all $X$. Calling $D:=A-C$, lets prove $D=0$.

We know that $\begin{pmatrix}DX\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}=0$ for all $X$, so expanding the matrix product we get
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1\begin{pmatrix}d_{11}\\\cdots\\d_{m1}\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}+\cdots+\lambda_n\begin{pmatrix}d_{1n}\\\cdots\\d_{mn}\end{pmatrix}_{B_2}=0
\end{equation}
which means that all the linear combinations of the vectors representing the columns of $D$ equals zero, and this can only happen if all of them are the zero vector. As long as all the unique coordinates of the zero vector in any basis are all zeroes, $D=0$, so $A-C=0$, then $A=C$, as we wanted to prove.

Comment: I'm missing just two things, why you can say that $f(e_{i}) = g(e_{i})$ and then why $f(e_{i})$ is of the form or better, i can write it like combination of $e_{i}^{'}$ and a combination of alpha coefficients index on ji where j=1 ... m and i is fixed

Comment: On one hand, I say that if you find some linear transformation $g$ which holds that $g(e_i)=f(e_i)$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, then $g$ must be equal to $f$. The fact that I proved is not that $f(e_i)=g(e_i)$, this is the hypothesis. On the other hand, $f(e_i)\in E_2$, and, as $B_2$ is a basis of $E_2$, any vector of $E_2$ can be writen uniquely as a linear combination of vectors of $B_2$, so we write $f(e_i)$ as a linear combination of vectors of $B_2$ (the only way we can). The name you give to the coefficients is arbitrary, I chose the alphas for comfort issues.

Comment: Okay no problem with that, i didn't just take the following part : 
"Lets go further, lets write f(x)∈E2
in coordinates with respect to B2, for this, lets suppose $f(e_{i})=α_{1i}e′_{1}+⋯+α_{mi}e′_{m}$ for all i∈{1,…,n}. My question was, why do you to specify the fixed i in the index ? Doesn't return always a column let's say we are in W, with dim W = m, of m rows and 1 column ? Is that kind of writing that i'm not understanding.

Comment: This is just a way of writing, nothing more, I use it to make a little bit more explicit that the coefficients corresponds to the coordinates of $f(e_i)$, but if you feel unconfortable with this, you can write it down the way you prefer. And yes, this coefficients always corresponds to the $i$-th column of the associated matrix, if you meant that.